Can someone help me find this sci-fi or fantasy book I saw in my High School library?
This may be a tough one because this book isn't very well known. But, I do remember it was on amazon.
I think it was published sometime around the mid 90s.
The art on the cover was in somewhat dark and purplish colors. The cover depicts alien looking ruins with columns that look like ones from Rome with a starry night sky.
The color of the title on the cover was either in neon green or neon yellow. Also, the sides of the letters of the title were covered in rock or stone.

Can you describe anything else other than the cover? Plot, characters, locations etc?

Somehow this makes me think of the cover of Foundation's Edge but there's no purple in the colour palette.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Was it a long title? One word? English? How much of the cover was the title? Any other details will help.

I think I have this book as your description rings a bell. However I'm working away from home and it'll be a week before I can check. In the mean time please provide more details e.g. was this a novel or an anthology? If it was a novel what was it about? If it was an anthology can you remember anything about the stories in it? If you can give us some more info to work with we will reopen your question.

Based on the cover description, this could be The Collected Short Fiction of C.J.Cherryh

@Devan - An anonymous user has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your accounts by following the instructions provided here. Once the accounts are merged, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from other users, leave comments within this thread, and mark an answer as accepted, if one is posted.

I'm home but I cannot find the book I'm thinking of. Either I've lost the book somewhere or more likely it was a ChatGPT style hallucination. Sorry :-(
